# How do I print a hash name in Perl?

Tags: perl

Kind of a simple question, but it has me stumped and google just lead me astray.  All I want to do is print out the name of a hash.  For example:

```
&my_sub(\%hash_named_bill);

&my_sub(\%hash_named_frank);

sub my_sub{

    my $passed_in_hash = shift;

    # do great stuff with the hash here

    print "You just did great stuff with: ". (insert hash name here);

}
```

The part I don't know is how to get the stuff in the parenthesis(insert...).  For a nested hash you can just use the "keys" tag to get the hash names (if you want to call them that).  I can't figure out how to get the entire hash name though, it seems like it really is just another key.

Comment: You can't.  The sub can't know the name of the hash.

Comment: the hash does not have a name, but the variable that points to it does, check out this post to see how to get access to the variable name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199860/get-variable-name-as-string-in-perl

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. This is one of those things that's possible in Perl, but that doesn't mean you should ever do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @hackattack said in the comment, the technical answer to your questions can be found in an answer to [Get variable name as string in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199860/get-variable-name-as-string-in-perl)

However, you should consider whether you are doing the right thing?

If you somehow need to know the name of the hash, you **most likely** would solve the problem better if you stash those multiple hashes into a hash-of-hashes with names being the keys (which you should be familiar with as you alluded to the approach in your question).

Comment: Nice, thank you for the tip.  I was trying to use the subroutine recursively.  I guess I could continue building the hash with names within the subroutine?

Comment: @thomas.cloud - quite correct. If you need help with that, drop in a new question with exact details of what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$hash_named_bill{name} = "bill";
$hash_named_frank{name} = "frank";

&my_sub(\%hash_named_bill);
&my_sub(\%hash_named_frank);

sub my_sub{

    my $passed_in_hash = shift;

    # do great stuff with the hash here

    print "You just did great stuff with: ". $passed_in_hash->{name};

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a name to refer to a hash, but hashes themselves don't have names. For example, consider the following:

```
*foo = {};
*bar = \%foo;
$foo{x} = 3;
$bar{y} = 4;
```

Keeping in mind the hash contains `(x=>3, y=>4)`: Is the hash nameless? named 'foo'? named 'bar'? All of the above? None of the above?

The best you can do is approximate an answer using [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PadWalker). I recommend against using it or similar (i.e. anything that finds a name) in production!

Answer (score 1):

A hash is just a piece of memory, to which a name (or more than one) can be associated.

If you want to print the name of the variable, that's not very straightforward (see haccattack comment), and doesn't smell very well (are you sure you really need that?)

You can also (if this fits your scenario) consider "soft (or symbolic) references" :

```
%hash1 = ( x => 101, y => 501);
%hash2 = ( x => 102, y => 502);

my_sub("hash1");
#my_sub(\%hash1);  # won't work
my_sub("hash2");

sub my_sub {
        my $hashname = shift;
        print "hash name: $hashname\n";
        print $hashname->{x} . "\n";
}
```

Here you are passing to the function the name of the variable, instead of a (hard) reference to it. Notice that, in Perl, this feels equivalent at the time of dereferencing it  (try uncommenting `my_sub(\%hash1);`), though it's quite a different thing.

Comment: Just as FYI: Using symbolic references is a neat trick but is generally considered a bad thing and should not be used in production code unless there is a good reason for it.

Comment: This works if you do not `use strict`, which I wouldn't recommend. You could turn off strict inside of `my_sub` as a compromise using `no strict` inside of `my_sub`.

Comment: A variable is an association between a name and storage. "Variable" refers to the association. The variable is not one of the things being associated. Fixed.