# Store the name of a hash, inside the hash

Tags: perl

Suppose I have a hash of hashes:

```
my %hash_of_hashes = (
    FOO => {
        BAR => "BAZ",
    },
    ALICE => {
        BOB => "CHARLIE",
    },
);
```

Now I want to add, for reasons, some meta-data: namely the name of the hash:

```
%hash_of_hashes = (
    FOO => {
        BAR => "BAZ",
        name => "hash_of_hashes",
    },
    ALICE => {
        BOB => "CHARLIE",
        name => "hash_of_hashes",
    },
);
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199860/get-variable-name-as-string-in-perl) and I could do this:

```
use Data::Dumper::Simple;
my ($var) = split /=/, Dumper(%hash_of_hashes);
```

but I think that call should be encapsulated in its own `sub` (since that's a weird operation). But if I put it in a `sub`, then `$var` doesn't contain `'%hash_of_hashes'`:

```
sub get_hash_name{
    my $h_ref = shift;
    my ($name) = split /=/, Dumper($href);
    return $name;
}
my $name = get_hash_name(\%hash_of_hashes); # $name contains $h_ref!
```

Is there any way to add on the name of the hash into the hash? (I realize [it's stupid to use a variable name in a variable](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), but I'm recursively parsing the hash and need to know what the "parent" hash was).

Comment: What about having a top level key `name` of each hash, and follow it as a protocol in your code? Then for any hash received read that field? But in this case you need create a hash using some kind of creator function which will set the name. Does this make any sense?

Comment: See also [Getting all arguments passed to a subroutine as a string in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361651/getting-all-arguments-passed-to-a-subroutine-as-a-string-in-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a reference to a sub, that's all it gets -- the reference. (If you were to pass a full hash it would get a list.)  We can't read off a name from the enclosing scope inside the sub directly.

However, there are modules that do the hard work.  Names of variables can be seen using [`PadWalker`](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/PadWalker-2.2/PadWalker.pm), for example.  Note their recommendation against using it "*directly in production code*".

There is a funciton `var_name` that fits this particular purpose exactly.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use PadWalker qw(var_name);

sub get_var_name { return var_name(1, $_[0]) }

my %hash_of_hashes = ( FOO => { BAR => "BAZ" }, ALICE => { BOB => "CHARLIE", } );

my $hash_name = get_var_name(\%hash_of_hashes);
```

The `$hash_name` has the string `%hash_of_hashes`.  As you don't want the sigil use

```
sub get_var_name { return substr var_name(1, $_[0]), 1 };
```

The `var_name(1, $_[0])` returns the name of the variable whose reference is the second argument, as long as that variable is in scope at `1` level above the sub where this function is called (so caller's).

This is a somewhat special case for what the module generally offers -- it reads names and values of all variables in scope at the given level (relative to where its functions are called). See the docs.

Answer (score 2):

[`Data::Dumper::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper::Simple) works by applying a *source filter*. It uses [`Filter::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::Simple) to modify the source code before it is compiled so that calls to `Dumper` pass the *names* of the parameters as well as their *values*

Rather than mess with the output of `Data::Dumper::Simple` I suggest you miss out the middle man and use `Filter::Simple` directly

I would write some example code, but you don't say enough about what you want to do

---

#### Update

Here's some example code. I've assumed that you just want a subroutine that, given a hash, will put the name of that hash in elements of the second-level hashes inside it

The module `AddName` contains both the source filter and the exported subroutine `add_name`. All calls in the main program to `add_name(%xxx)` or `add_name(\%xxx)` are converted to `add_name(\%xxx, 'xxx')`, so the subroutine knows the name of the hash and can insert it easily

Beware of source filters: they are a very rough and ready way of making your code do what you want, and while I have coded for some leeway in where whitespace may appear, it is not an exact science and nothing this simple can fully emulate the perl parser itself

#### AddName.pm

```
package AddName;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw/ add_name /;

use Filter::Simple sub {
    s/ \b add_name \s* \( \s* \\? %(\w+) \s* \) /add_name(\\\%$1, '$1')/gx;
};

sub add_name {
    my ($hash, $name) = @_;
    $_->{name} = $name for values %$hash;
}

1;
```

#### test.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use AddName;
use Data::Dump;

my %hash_of_hashes = (
    FOO => {
        BAR => "BAZ",
    },
    ALICE => {
        BOB => "CHARLIE",
    },
);

add_name(\%hash_of_hashes);

dd \%hash_of_hashes;
```

#### output

```
{
  ALICE => { BOB => "CHARLIE", name => "hash_of_hashes" },
  FOO => { BAR => "BAZ", name => "hash_of_hashes" },
}
```