# How to recover a element name used as parameter in a subroutine?

Tags: perl, parameters, subroutine

I'm guessing if it's possible to recover or save inside a scalar the "items" names used as parameters for a subroutine.

The following code explains better what I'm referring

```
sub test_array{

    print "\n";
    print "TESTING ARRAY ".%%ARRAY_NAME%%."\n";
    print "\n";
    print " \'".join ("\' , \'" , @_)."\'"."\n";
    print "\n";

}

@list= qw/uno dos tres/;

test_array(@list);
```

So the goal is to have a subroutine called "test_array" that prints the name and content of the array is being passed to subroutine as parameter.

What I would like is to print the array name where "%%ARRAY_NAME%%" is.

Is there any way to recover this using special variables or to save this as a string inside a scalar?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Because the short answer is "no" but there may be ways to achieve a similar goal.

Comment: Why should a subroutine care about the names of the variables that are being passed to it?

Comment: I want to do this because I need to see in the prints the name of the array being tested and how it's evolving, taking in mind I'm going to call this subroutine several times and using several arrays as parameter, this could help me a lot.

Comment: See also [Getting all arguments passed to a subroutine as a string in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36361651/2173773) and [Store the name of a hash, inside the hash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36558998/2173773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be much better off just sending in two parameters... the array's 'name', and the array itself:

```
sub test_array {
    my ($name, @array) = @_;
    print "array: $name\n";
    print join ', ', @array;
}
```

Then:

```
my @colours = qw(orange green);
test_array('colours', @colours);

...

my @cities = qw(toronto edmonton);
test_array('cities', @cities);
```

Or even:

```
test_array('animals', qw(cat dog horse));
```

Another way that may help automate things a bit, is use a global hash to store the array's location as the key, with it's name as the value, then pass the array reference to the sub:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %arrs;

my @animals = qw(cat dog);

$arrs{\@animals} = 'animals';

my @colours = qw(orange green);

$arrs{\@colours} = 'colours';

test_array(\@animals);
test_array(\@colours);

sub test_array {
    my $array = shift;

    print "$arrs{$array}\n";

    print join ', ', @$array;
    print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
animals
cat, dog
colours
orange, green
```

Comment: Thanks stevieb, this could be the most usefull thing I could do, as it seems, there's not any way to do what I was asking, or at least not in a easy way.

Answer (score 0):

[Data::Dumper::Names](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Dumper-Names) does this using `peek_my` (from [PadWalker](https://metacpan.org/pod/PadWalker)) and `refaddr` (from [Scalar::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util)). But I suspect it's fragile and I wouldn't recommend it.

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this module and see what happends.

What I'm trying is to call this subroutine in multiple lines of a program and know wich array is testing at certain point and how the arrays are 'evolving'

Comment: @shayk_87: I'm not saying that Data::Dumper::Names will solve your problem. I'm saying that you can look at the source code and use a similar approach.